# Sorting area by specific column

Tags: excel, vba, function, sorting

I am trying to build a function that will input:
i) a worksheet
ii) a sorting area
iii) a sorting column header (where this column has dates in it).

The code will then sort the area in ascending order.

```
Function sortArea(Sheet As Worksheet, sortingArea As Range, sortingColHeader As Range) As Range

With Sheet.sort
    .SortFields.Add Key:=Range(sortingColHeader), Order:=xlAscending
    .SetRange Range(sortingArea)
    .Header = xlYes
    .Apply
End With

End Function
```

When I write, in my main sub:

```
Call sortArea(Sheets(2), Range("A16:AP45"), Range("I14"))
```

I get:

> "runtime error 1004 Method range of object Global failed"

on the first line within the With-block:

```
.SortFields.Add Key:=Range(sortingColHeader), Order:=xlAscending
```

Comment: Care to let us know which line shows the error?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that. Its the first line within the With-block: ".SortFields.Add Key..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Examine the differences:

```
Option Explicit

Sub sortArea(ws As Worksheet, sortingArea As Range, sortingColHeader As Range)

With ws.Sort
    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add Key:=sortingColHeader, Order:=xlDescending
    .SetRange sortingArea
    .Header = xlYes
    .Apply
End With

End Sub

Sub tester()
Call sortArea(Sheets(2), Range("b1:c10"), Range("b1:b10"))
End Sub
```

- Use a Sub instead of a Function.  You want to act on the worksheet.  In general, functions return a result to the caller.
- The sort key is described as a range representing the entire column, not as a single cell.
- The `Range(Range)` syntax doesn't make sense.
- *ignore the change in the `order` parameter, that was just for testing*
- Note the `.SortFields.Clear` otherwise you just keep adding `SortFields` each time you run the macro

For documentation sake, consider changing `sortingColHeader` to `sortingColRange`